# How can I view the bandwidth usage of a specific interface over a period of time on Fortinet without using a FortiAnalyzer instance?

Tags: firewall, bandwidth, fortinet

My company utilizes a Fortinet firewall, but we currently do not have a FortiAnalyzer. We are seeking to obtain statistics on the usage of an internet interface's bandwidth, specifically over a 24-hour period. How can we achieve this without a FortiAnalyzer instance?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SNMP to extract the interface usage into one of many monitoring applications.

If you need to split that traffic up on the network layer (IP addresses) or on the transport layer (port numbers), sFlow or NetFlow could cover that, as Ricky suggested.

Product recommendations are off topic here, however.

Comment: However, with SNMP, we are unable to obtain details such as destination website visits, users' IP addresses, and the source and destination information. It lacks these specific details

Comment: You were asking about interface bandwidth which is possible via SNMP. Connection details are a completely different thing and need to be extracted from the logs.

Comment: That level of detail is into the realm of netflow/sflow.